# change background dynamically by using only css

Tags: css

IS there a way to change background dynamically by using only css.

My background images are not fixed. I am setting the style from JS like

```
var background = '';
//backgroundForCurrUser is an array of URL coming from server
for(var x in backgroundForCurrUser) 
{
   background += 'url('+ backgroundForCurrUser[x]+ '),';
}
background = background.substring(0,background.length-1);

var element = document.getElementById("myDashoboard");
element.style.setProperty('background', background );
```

```
<div id="myDashoboard"><div>
```

Is there a way that I can slide show the background images with css with one image at a time and irrespective of the number of images?

Comment: You could try [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

Comment: https://codepen.io/klesht/pen/vEOjrz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @zevee commented, you may use CSS animation on `background-image` property, here is an example :

```css
@keyframes change {
    30%   {background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/400/);}
    50%  {background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/400/);}
    80% {background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/400/);}
}

.myDashoboard {
   background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/400/);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-size:cover;
    position: relative;
    animation: change 5s linear 1s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDashoboard">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! is it possible to show ( . . .) along with the background change with only css? and click of each dot it should show the image and slide should continue as well?

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy you can add dots, this it ok, but you said **click** so i think it's gonna be difficult as CSS doesn't handle clicks, but you can for example use hover instead of click (when you hover on dot image change) but it will be very diffcult too. I don't think that you can create a full slider with only CSS. You can have something very similar but not with all the known interaction